# Reloading data on window.open child

Tags: angular

I`m opening a new window using window.open. This window contains some items that need to be refreshed when an event happens in the parent window.

Although I can see that the event has reached the new window and the data is fetched, the view is not refreshed until I resize the window which somehow reloads the items.

In the parent:

```
window.open('/popup');
```

In the new window I have the create items function that creates the correct array:

```
createItems(items) {
    this.items= new Array<Items>();
    this.items.push(items.current);
    this.items.push(items.next);
    if (items.history) {
      items.history.forEach(item=> {
        this.items.push(item);
      });
    }
  }
```

And the HTML:

```
<app-item *ngFor="let item of items" [item]="item"></app-item>
```

Comment: Can you share your code that processes the event? Its likely angular is not aware any values have changed. You can force angular to detect changes by injecting the ChangeDetectorRef into your component and calling detectChanges() after you fetch the new data and set it to the items variable.

Comment: I initially used an EventEmitter but Ive switched to a BroadcastChannel since I thought that was the problem 

`this.bc= new BroadcastChannel('bc');
    this.bc.onmessage = (items) => {
      this.createItems(items);
    };`

I have also used the detectChanges() after the Array is created but that doesn`t make a difference

Comment: Yep angular isn't aware of any changes made that occur in that scope. Import and inject `changeDetectorRef` in your constructor and add `this.changeDetectorRef.detectchanges()` after `this.createItems(items);`. Generally you should avoid using `changeDetectorRef`, but in this case you don't have much choice.

Comment: I used the `this.changeDetectorRef.detectchanges()` as you mentioned and it seems it fixed the problem. Thank you for your help